How do I deploy permissions module to my safe? The current one I try to deploy fails
I am currently trying to deploy permissions smart contract as module to my Safe wallet. It fails on sign stage and reverts, I assume my contract fails to conform to rules modules have to follow. Would appreciate pointers how to resolve the problem.

A bit more about what I want to achieve - I want to use Safe wallet with 2 signers (with 1 being required for executing transaction), but I want to let 1 of the signers to have limited functionality (let's say interacting only with designated addresses (might be static or modifiable by 'owner' address.) So I might be taking the wrong approach altogether.)


Smart contract I intend to use as module 0x2cb4d32d17c6dd2cad7d7304b26f954889338c31
My Safe wallet has 2 signers, I do want them to have different permissions (I did add it in my smart contract).
This is the simulation of transaction on tenderly: https://dashboard.tenderly.co/public/safe/safe-apps/simulator/9d5a2f93-935a-4f60-9405-4def799225a9
This is the contract code:


contract AllowanceModule {
    address public owner;
    address public user;
    address public allowedAddress;

    constructor(address _owner, address _user, address _allowedAddress) {
        owner = _owner;
        user = _user;
        allowedAddress = _allowedAddress;
    }

    modifier onlyUser() {
        require(msg.sender == user, "Not the user");
        _;
    }

    function execute(address _to, uint256 _value, bytes calldata _data) external onlyUser {
        require(_to == allowedAddress, "Not allowed to interact with this address");
        (bool success, ) = _to.call{value: _value}(_data);
        require(success, "Transaction failed");
    }

    receive() external payable {}
}```


I would add your contract as a Guard rather than a module for this use-case, as the code in your contract should execute before every transaction.
You can see here how to add a guard from the UI, or call setGuard on your Safe to add a guard directly at the contract level.
The Zodiac Guard Scope could also provide a good inspiration as the use-case is closely similar.
I hope it answers your question. If yes, feel free to mark it as solved; let me know if that's not the case.
Thanks in advance! Best, Louis

hi, thanks for reply. I deployed my guard contract using base from safe-git repo. But I am still facing issue with adding it to my safe wallet using WebUI. In tenderly can see errors:
https://dashboard.tenderly.co/public/safe/safe-apps/simulator/b541bed8-7b34-412c-a2a3-b0aa737065c4
there come up 2 errors:
GS013 and GS031
it seems like after signing my transaction not safe, but signer becomes sender and tx fails "selfAuthorized" check.

Hello, Louis. Unfortunately, I still wasn't able to resolve issue, would appreciate help or any reply that is, thanks.
